# Upload ZIP to indexedDB offline

Tags: javascript, file-upload, zip, offline, indexeddb

I am building a web application/editor that I want to be able to be used offline.  This editor will store file data in the browser's `indexedDB`, but I need the user to be able to download a copy of this data as a `.zip` archive and upload a `.zip` to be stored in `indexedDB` -- all offline.

Is there any way to, using a file upload or drag-and-drop API, get the contents of a `.zip` to manipulate in Javascript, without using any server-side scripts?  Are there any libraries to unzip an archive and get the files in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one really handy client side zip library [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/). I've used it for exporting `indexeddb` content into `xml` files and zip them before download, using the `file system api`.

I would recommend you saving the data in the native form inside `indexeddb`, so that it would be easier for manipulating it, and use the zip and unzip feature of [this library](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) when importing and exporting the data.

Comment: Yea, I found zip.js myself 10 seconds before you posted this.  I am planning on storing the data in native format.  Thanks.